# Windows 8 Live Tiles Badge Image / Text

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-metro, winrt-xaml, live-tile

I've been following [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsappdev/archive/2012/04/16/creating-a-great-tile-experience-part-1.aspx) example, and now have a working live tile.  However, my tile displays with a small cross on the bottom left hand corner of the tile.  In the example, this displays as a little truck.  How is this set?

I can't see where it specifies it in the article.  At first, I thought this might be the "Badge" icon specified in the app manifest, but that doesn't display there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The image in those tile updates draws from the "Small logo" 30x30 pixel image in the manifest (Package.appxmanifest).

Tile branding and can also be the app's name (or nothing if you'd like).  Some design/usage pointers here - [Guidelines and checklist for tiles and badges (Windows Store apps)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465403.aspx).

Default functionality is set via the "Small logo", "Display name"/"Short name", and "Show name" settings, but you can specify [binding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br212854.aspx) right in your tile update (e.g. to hide logo/name for certain tile updates).