# Win8 Metro UI & Small logo

Tags: xml, windows-8, live-tile

In my program for Win8 Store i want to use a Small Logo on Live Tile. I set image uri into application manifest rebuild and launch it. But i don't see Small logo on tile in the bottom left-hand corner. I'm using next XML for creating the Live Tile

```
<tile>
    <visual branding="logo">
        <binding template="TileWideSmallImageAndText04">
            <image id="1" src="bla bla bla.png" alt="alt text"/>
            <text id="1">BLA BLA</text>
            <text id="2">BLA BLA</text>
        </binding>
        <binding template="TileSquareText02">
            <text id="1">BLA</text>
            <text id="2">BLA</text>
        </binding>
    </visual>
</tile>
```

What am I doing incorrect to set the small logo on the Live Tile?

Answer (score 0):

checkout [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12707806/windows-8-live-tiles-badge-image-text) answer

The image in those tile updates draws from the "Small logo" 30x30 pixel image in the manifest (Package.appxmanifest).

Tile branding and can also be the app's name (or nothing if you'd like).  Some design/usage pointers here - [Guidelines and checklist for tiles and badges (Windows Store apps)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465403.aspx).

Default functionality is set via the "Small logo", "Display name"/"Short name", and "Show name" settings, but you can specify [binding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br212854.aspx) right in your tile update (e.g. to hide logo/name for certain tile updates).